# Index a varchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I asked Google but I am still confused.

1) Is there a problem in indexing a Varchar column.  When I shouldn't, and When I should

2) Index a char column VS Varchar column.

Thanks

Comment: If u can support an existing answer, or have something to add, please do that.

Answer (score 5):

1 - Index it if  you are querying it and it is selective enough.  If it is a column where 90% of the values are the same, there won't be much point.

2 - This is not a question, but I will guess you want to know if you should.  Yes, if you query it and it meets the criteria above.

Comment: Indeed, indexing (N)varchar columns works fine. Only gotcha would be to watch out for the 900 byte width limitation

Comment: There are index issues with varchar(max) and nvarchar (max) which is why they shouldn't be used unless you intend to overflow the size of the ordinary varchar and nvarchar field.

Comment: You cannot create an index on an nvarchar(max) or varchar(max) by itself. It can be part of the another index but not the primary lookup part of the index. These data types are meant to only be used for large pieces of data and not for the types of fields you need to index. Many people think it is easier to use them instead of taking the time to correctly size their columns and then they end up with an unidexable mess  and a datbase that is slower than a slug.

Comment: to quote Books Online:"Columns that are of the large object (LOB) data types ntext, text, varchar(max), nvarchar(max), varbinary(max), xml, or image cannot be specified as key columns for an index."

Comment: @HGLEM - It makes sense when I think about it (why they would be unindexable) but I didn't realize it was a constraint.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 4):

- ad 1) Yes, 900 bytes limit, huge keys, lots of index pages, lots of I/O involved, inefficient index operations. Conclusion: DON'T unless your `varchar` is about 50 chars max.
- ad 2) Same as 1. The real difference between `char` vs. `varchar` are fixed size vs. variable size (ie. `char(100)`) always takes 100 bytes in data page, `varchar(100)` takes up to 100)

Answer (score 0):

Generally performance

In theory/design, you have a logical model where, say, username is unique.

However, at implementation time you know that to use this is expensive (case, accents, length etc) compared to using a surrogate "userid" column which is more efficient as an index. Saying that, you'd have an index on name anyway because it should be unique.

The difference would be where you use this index: if it's in a child table as a foreign key column, it's not a good idea. Or as a clustered index.

As a single index for a table with no FKs, then it's neither here nor there.

Finally, I would just use the char/varchar for stuff like ISO language or currency codes (DE, EN, GBP, CHF etc). But my cut off varies to be honest...